# Apache BeanUtils: BooleanConverter

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-beanutils

How do I use the [BooleanConverter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.1/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/converters/BooleanConverter.html) class???

The `BooleanConverter` class is final. But the method [`<T> T convertToType(Class<T> type, Object value)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.1/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/converters/BooleanConverter.html#convertToType%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) is protected... (why would they design it like that?)

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
Converter converter = new BooleanConverter(Boolean.TRUE);
Boolean b = converter.convert(Boolean.TYPE, someMethodThatReturnsSomething());
```

Isn't the `Converter`'s method [`<T> T convert(Class<T> type, Object value)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.1/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/Converter.html#convert%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) supposed to return a `Boolean` object then.....?

However I'm getting the following compilation error:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Boolean`

**UPDATE:**

With the repliers' answers, I was able to got it working.  It seems like I had to explicitly add to my pom the latest `commons-beanutils-core`, since it was overriden by older dependency I had in my pom.xml.

This is how my pom looks now:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

BTW, what I was trying to do is to find a way to execute non-boolean (non-void) methods from within an `if` predicate:

```
Converter converter = new BooleanConverter(Boolean.TRUE);
if (converter.convert(Boolean.class, some_Method_That_Changes_Status_And_Returns_Non_Boolean()) && some_Boolean_Method_That_Checks_The_Status())
{
//......
}
else if (converter.convert(Boolean.class, some_Other_Method_That_Changes_Status_And_Returns_Non_Boolean()) && some_Boolean_Method_That_Checks_The_Status())
{
//......
}
else
{
//......
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using version 1.9.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Boolean b = converter.convert(Boolean.class, someMethodThatReturnsSomething());
```

The `convert` method is supported to return a T where T is specified by the Class provided as the first parameter (i.e. the return value's type depends in the first parameter's type).

It looks like the above should work if `someMethodThatReturnsSomething()` returns a String.  If it doesn't, it's not so clear what should happen (it might be a runtime exception).

UPDATE:

Oh! Change:

```
Converter converter = new BooleanConverter(Boolean.TRUE);
```

To:

```
BooleanConverter converter = new BooleanConverter(Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: Method's signature allows me to use any object as the second parameter. Is this a "bug"?

Comment: I would assume it would call the `BooleanConverter` methods through polymorphism.... the change you suggested didn't solve the problem. I still see the problem even when I change the second parameter to a `String`. It's a compilation error (on Eclipse).

Comment: I've just been reading the Javadoc a bit.  Do you have to use that library?  It's horrible.  (For example, the `Converter` interface isn't properly genericized; it ought to be `Converter<T>`.)

Comment: (And, looking at the source, it's even worse.)

Comment: It would have been hard to make the `Converter` generic. The implementation of converting a boolean would be totally different than converting a truck. I don't have to use Commons. I'm looking for a library that can convert anything to a boolean (or to true if it cannot be accomplished). Any ideas? BTW, some people don't like Commons. But I don't think it's a "buggy" library. People might not like its design in some cases.

Comment: using `commons-beanutils-core` 1.8.0 & `commons-beanutils` 1.8.0, according to Eclipse's maven dependency hierarchy.

Comment: @rapt Upgrade, the method definitions you see are from 1.9+. Previously, the return type was `Object`.

Comment: @rapt I don't think it is necessarily buggy, just over complicated and under specified.  A 'converter' is really just a `Function<V,R>` (or perhaps `Function<V,R> throws ConvertException`) so should probably be typed `Converter<V,R>` with each implementation simple and targeted to the two types.  I'd probably have returned most of the converters from factory methods, hiding the implementation, e.g. `public static Converter<String,Boolean> strToBool(List<String> falses, List<String> trues)`.  Composite converters I'd assemble from the individual converters (but with less specific types).

Comment: BTW I seem to have picked up the kudos for rapt's answer (in the comment above).  Perhaps rapt could make that an actual answer and you could accept that instead?  (If you *can* change the excepted answer.)